# ServiceNow as container based application

Tags: kubernetes, containers, servicenow

Can we run servicenow as a containerised application on a cluster or a VM rather than using it as SaaS or Paas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to speak with your ServiceNow Sales Rep.

There is a configuration of ServiceNow which can be run in a customer data center (as opposed SaaS). However, it may be that this exists only for large legacy customers who have been running the product this way for many years, and have been grandfathered in. It may not be available as an option for new customers.